# Android AVD error: "The selected skin was not found. Check your AVD configuration and try again later."

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, kindle-fire

Creating emulator for Kindle Fire:
Android 2.3.3 API Level 10
Screen res 600x1024 density 169, heap 24, ram 512

Click Start, get this error:

```
Android AVD Error: The selected skin was not found. Check your AVD configuration and try again later.
```

I am setting the Skin resolution to the Kindle Fire custom value so I am not using a Built-in. The emulator will run, but will not run in debug from Eclipse due to this error. If I start a debug session the emulator that is running closes and the error comes up and thats the end of the debug session.

Comment: did u found any solution.

Comment: No I never did. I used a different device to debug with and just tested resizing with Kindle.